# Drop down list with the style of an range

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, worksheet

Without use app script (i want make my sheet lighter), how i can set a drop down style on a define range ? Like we can define the values from this way but how about the style ? I need to do this because i use this range for different things.

I have this range :
[image]

With them i want create this kind of drop down :

[image]

But when you define a drop down with a range, you get only the values and not the style so like this :
[image]

Change the colors with apps script is really heavy so i would like do it differently ))

Thank you in advance ^^

Comment: what is plage? Please provide example.  It's clear what you are talking about

Comment: Sorry for my english haha. A range, like from the cell C2 to C9, i want create a drop down base on this cell (for the values AND the style)

Comment: I don't understand try providing an example of what you want

Comment: I have add an exemple

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to apply colors to dropdowns as shown in the screenshot below.  **But there is no way to do so automatically without the use of a script.**

[image: Example]

Go to the Data Validation rules for the cell and the colors can be customized there.

[image: Example 2]

It will look like this with data entered.

[image: Example 3]

If you add categories, you can customize them after adding them to the range you are using for your Data Validation.

Comment: Sorry but i want someting automatic and not manually. I want it get the style of the range. The same way that it get the values. It's not use in only column so all change manually is just a good way to do. I already make a request for this feature in case

Comment: I've modified my answer to reflect what you are looking for.  The unfortunate answer is that unless you are willing to manually change the colors in the Data Validation, then you will need to use a script to achieve what you desire.

Comment: Well yes sad :/ I already use a script for do it but it's slow haha I don't understand why Google propose to made it with a range but not the possibility to take the range style too. Anyway, thanks ))